# Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem (With Sqrt Term)

Tags: contour-integration

I am reading up on the Sokhotski-Plemelj theorem, and so far I've seen it being applied on equation with the general form (ref: [http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph214/Plemelj.pdf](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph214/Plemelj.pdf)):

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1}{x-x_0\pm i\epsilon} = P\frac{1}{x-x_0} \mp i\pi\delta(x-x_0)$$

Can the same theorem be applied to the following equation with an additional sqrt term?
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x_0\pm i\epsilon}}$$

I can only think of bringing out the sqrt term and applying the formula to get the same result but with the additional sqrt term:

$$\sqrt{\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1}{x-x_0\pm i\epsilon}} = \sqrt{P\frac{1}{x-x_0} \mp i\pi\delta(x-x_0)}$$

Is there any way to simplify that? Or is there another way of applying the theorem? Thank you.